# SimpleDateFormat with only milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, milliseconds

I **must** use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse a date in Java. I'm using an existing library that takes a date as `String` and a `SimpleDateFormat` instance to parse it.
Everything is fine, but I'm having trouble if the date format consists in only milliseconds since epoch time (1/1/1970), i.e. UNIX time in milliseconds. Using `new SimpleDateFormat("SS")` or `new SimpleDateFormat("SSS")` didn't work:

Code to reproduce the strange `SimpleDateFormat` behavior:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // just for the test
long currTimeInMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();

SimpleDateFormat msSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("SS");  // same result with SimpleDateFormat("SSS")
SimpleDateFormat secSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");

System.out.println(msSDF.parse("" + currTimeInMilli));
System.out.println(secSDF.parse("" + (currTimeInMilli / 1000)));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy").format(currTimeInMilli));
```

Produced output:

```
Mon Dec 15 07:46:20 GMT 1969    <-- should be like two other lines (?)!
Mon Apr 28 20:55:19 GMT 2014    <-- OK
Mon Apr 28 20:55:19 GMT 2014    <-- OK
```

Is it normal? How can I set up a `SimpleDateFormat` able to parse milliseconds elapsed since the *epoch*?

**Notes:**

- I cannot use other libraries like Joda-time
- I cannot use `new Date(long pNbMilli)` to construct the date (legacy library is taking a `SimpleDateFormat` instance as input)
- I found this [filed JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039167) but not sure it is directly bound to this issue...

Comment: and no calendar  allowed?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin nope :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `S` pattern won't properly handle a number of milliseconds greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, as bizarre as that may seem for a quantity normally expressed as a long.

If you really must use an existing API that demands a DateFormat you can always hack it in:

```
SimpleDateFormat msSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("SSS") {

            @Override
            public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException {
                return new Date(Long.parseLong(source));
            }

};
```

(May need to also provide a hacked implementation of `format(string)` too depending on what your legacy API actually does of course.)

Comment: Thank you. Good idea. So shouldn't it be reported as a bug in `SimpleDateFormat`?